# Xcode, is it possible to type in co-ordinates and then get location?

Tags: xcode

I was wondering if this type of task is possible and if so how can it could be done or is there a tutorial on this? I believe a task like this involve collocation ,but I am not for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reverse Geocoding made simple](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_clgeocoder/)

thats a great tutorial for reverse Geocoding. Adapt what they show you to switch input of a place to input of the coordinate and you will have what you want.